# Laravel - Ionic login doesn't work on a local machine

Tags: laravel, ionic-framework

I have setup the backend on both local machine and a production server.

```
    angular.module('coop').constant('AppSettings', {
       //apiUrl: 'http://myApp.laravel.productionServer.no/api',
       //mediaServer: 'http://myApp.laravel.productionServer.no'
       apiUrl: 'http://myApp.app/api',
       mediaServer: 'http://myApp.app'
    })
```

When I am connecting to the api on the production server everything works fine, but when I am connected to my local machine and try to log in by running the app on an android device I get:

> MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line

It works fine when I am loggin in the app on both browser and emulator on local server, it just doesn't work when I try to do it with a phone. 
This is are my routes for authentication:

```
Route::group(['jwt.auth', ['except' => ['authenticate', 'share']], 'prefix' => 'api', 'namespace' => 'Api'], function() {
    Route::post('authenticate', 'AuthenticateController@authenticate');
    Route::get('authenticate/user', 'AuthenticateController@getAuthenticatedUser');

... rest of the routes
```

And this is the controller responsible for authentication:

```
public function __construct()
{
    // Apply the jwt.auth middleware to all methods in this controller
    // except for the authenticate method. We don't want to prevent
    // the user from retrieving their token if they don't already have it
    $this->middleware('jwt.auth', ['except' => ['authenticate']]);
}

/**
 * Authenticate a user from a request containing
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function authenticate(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->only('phone', 'password');

    try {
        // verify the credentials and create a token for the user
        if (!$token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 401);
        }
    } catch (JWTException $e) {
        // something went wrong
        return response()->json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token'], 500);
    }

    $user = User::where('phone', $credentials['phone'])->firstOrFail();

    // if no errors are encountered we can return a JWT
    return response()->json([
        'token' => $token,
        'user' => $user,
    ]);
}

public function getAuthenticatedUser() {
    try {
        if (! $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate()) {
            return response()->json(['user_not_found'], 404);
        }
    } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException $e) {
        return response()->json(['token_expired'], $e->getStatusCode());
    } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException $e) {
        return response()->json(['token_invalid'], $e->getStatusCode());
    } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException $e) {
        return response()->json(['token_absent'], $e->getStatusCode());
    }

    // the token is valid and we have found the user via the sub claim
    return response()->json(compact('user'));
}
```

Comment: debug the app check if correct data is being sent to the server or if data is actually sent or not. Wrong password may be coming as the request will be getting failed.

Comment: I have forgot to mention that, in the console, it seems like I am sending the right data, but for some reason, it is not letting me log in.

Comment: Are you receiving the correct response from request ?  Go to `Network Panel` after `Inspect Element` and make request, `select request` -> `response` check if server is sending the correct data

Comment: I don't get any response, not sure why is this happening, I have edited the question with the code from the backend.

Comment: means you backend code has some issue...check if `phone` value provided is actually present or not..